# Return rss feed from an angularjs route

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create a frontend with angularjs for an app that generates rss feeds. So i want to configure a route that will render the rss.

So the basic idea is, when a user goes to `http://myserver/#/myTopic/rss` the server should return the result of the following api call `http://myserver/api/1/myTopic/rss`

So I created my route as below.

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
    // render rss feed
    when('/:topic/rss', {
      controller: 'rssCtrl'
    });
}]);
```

And the `rssCtrl` is defined like this

```
var rssCtrl = function($scope, $location, $routeParams) {
  // what to put in it??
};
app.controller('rssCtrl', rssCtrl);
```

I'm conceptually stuck on what to put in my controller, since I don't want the index.html to be rendered (my single page app) but the rss feed.

Any ideas? thoughts?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is possible. Angular is a client-side framework, i.e. it works by sending the JavaScript to the browser where it generates the HTML. You cannot assume that an RSS feed reader will interpret JavaScript, in fact most don't since it's considered a security risk. So you need to generate the RSS feed on the server-side.

Comment: The feed is generated on the server-side (see http://rss-unify.herokuapp.com/api/1/js/rss) so what I need is just a redirection from http://rss-unify.herokuapp.com/#/js/rss to http://rss-unify.herokuapp.com/api/1/js/rss in that case.

Answer (score 0):

> The $location service allows you to change only the URL; it does not allow you to reload the page. When you need to change the URL and reload the page or navigate to a different page, please use a lower level API, $window.location.href. -- [$location](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.%24location)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, it seems it's what I'm looking for, but I can't make it work. Here is the route ```when('/:topic/rss', {controller: 'rssCtrl'})``` and the controller only execute the followng line ```function($window) {$window.location.href = $window.location.href.replace('#','api/1');}``` And I'm still on the index.html page, and it seems this controller is not executed when I debug. Weird?!

Comment: @xavier, I believe the route object/argument to the when() method must have a template or a templateUrl specified.  Try that and see if it helps.